# Get total count of duplicates in column

Tags: sql, count, duplicates

I need a query to count the total number of duplicates in a table, is there any way to do this?

If I have a table like this:

```
+------------+----------+
| item_name  |quantity  |
+------------+----------+
| Calculator |       89 |
| Notebooks  |       40 |
| Pencil     |       40 |
| Pens       |       32 |
| Shirts     |       29 |
| Shoes      |       29 |
| Trousers   |       29 |
+------------+----------+
```

I can't use `SELECT COUNT(quantity)` because it returns 2. (`40 | 29`)

How can I return 5? (`40 | 40 | 29 | 29 | 29`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY quantity) cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work except that I think `SELECT COUNT(*)` should be changed to `SELECT SUM(cnt)`

Comment: I disagree, at least if you expect a count of 5 from your sample table.

Comment: Yep you're right I was looking at the table wrong

Answer (score 1):

One method uses two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(cnt)
from (select quantity, count(*) as cnt
      from t 
      group by quantity
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Interestingly, if you wanted "3" -- the number of rows that have duplicates, you could express this as:

```
select count(*) - count(distinct quantity)
from t;
```

But that is not what you are asking for.